# Return to Access form after running an excel file from VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

After I open and then close an excel file from VBA code in Access, I don't return to the database but another open window (presumably the last visited?)

Tried several variations with the Docmd function, to not avail

```
Public Function Open_Share_Price_Excel()

' Change Cursor to Hourglass
DoCmd.Hourglass (True)




Dim Expath As String
Dim ModName As String
Dim XLApp As Object
Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'
'Define where the Excel Spreadsheet is and the module to run
'

Expath = "C:\Users\peter\Documents\Financial Affairs\Shares\Share Price Bing.xlsm"
ModName = "Combined_Module"



With XLApp
    .Application.Visible = True
    .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .UserControl = True
    Dim OpenedWb As Object
    Set OpenedWb = .Workbooks.Open(Expath)
    .Run ModName
    OpenedWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End With

XLApp.Quit
Set XLApp = Nothing

'Change Cursor back and display finished message

DoCmd.Hourglass (False)
DoCmd.SelectObject 2, "Portfolio Valuation", True

MsgBox ("Price Update Finished - OK to Continue")


End Function
```

I just want to be able to return to Access and the form that has a control button that runs this code!

Comment: Can you please be more precise? If you run the code from the button in Access, and the code doesn't open any other windows than the Excel application, then the last visited window (after closing Excel) was Access. If you just want to activate Access, then use the [Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activatemicrosoftapp) like `Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess`

Comment: I've never had this issue. Focus returns to Access when Excel closes. What does the Excel module code do?

Comment: I have commented out the line that runs the module as I am testing solutions. Hence all the code does is open a spreadsheet and then close it again. The symptom after closing the Excel spreadsheet is that instead of MS Access being the top open window, most commonly the top open window is the folder where the files all exist. Sometimes it will just have the open browser as the top window.

Comment: Is there problem created by this being a function not a sub?

Comment: The suggested code Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess produces a compile error Method or data member not found

Comment: What about changing `.Application.Visible = True` to `False`? That way Excel won't get any focus, and you should stay in Access Windows.

Comment: I did same test with your code (with my filepath of course). Also commented out `SelectObject` line. Focus returns to Access.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following functions may help, I have not tried them in a similar context, but may be it will work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "User32" ()
' get the  windows handle of the Access window. You may also get it from the 
' Hwnd property of the form.
dim hwnd as long
hwnd = GetActiveWindow()

your code to perform the excel functions.

'then show the window again
ShowWindow hwnd, 5

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting and look at the answers others provided, I think that the resolution mya lie in the VBA code that it is executed inside the Excel spreadsheet. At the end of the code, but before I exited,  I had the line:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

which when I commented out seemed solve my problem. Go figure!

Thank you for all who tried to solve this issue for me. Go well!